# How AMD FX 8250 can run x86/x32 Virtual Machines in VMWare Player or VirtualBox (Without ESXi)?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

For running both `x86 and x64 bit` virtual machines using `VMWare Player` and `Virtual Box` both from time to time (***No ESXi's***). Does AMD FX8350 suffice ?.

If `YES` which motherboard else which CPU + Motherboard to seek for or related `must-have` technical feature. Like VTx, VTd, IMMO ... many are there ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AMD FX8350 is a 8-core CPU and suitable for virtualization. Although lower in performance in latest i7 CPUs but I can dedicate different CPUs to each OS thereby making system responsive.

I found motherboards like gigabyte `ga-b150m-ds3h` with built in `VT-d` which allows VMs to directly use underlying hardware bypassing host OS. So final solution is to `have a multicore intel CPU and board with VT-d`. To remove ESXi one can use recent `container os` called `smart os` which is pretty cool.